# Linux - How to list all device nodes using a specific device driver

Tags: linux, drivers, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I know I can see what driver is being used for a device node if I know the major and minor number of the device(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911050/linux-how-do-i-know-the-module-that-exports-a-device-node) link).

But I want to know if there's a way to list all device nodes that are using a particular driver by just giving the driver name.

Say the name of the device driver is 'vpfe-capture', then I'd want to know all device nodes using 'vpfe-capture'.

This would save the time of manually searching through each device node in /sys/dev/ just to see which nodes use a particular driver.